# Python Regex for beginning and ending word

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a regex that will find "Vlan20" and the word "up" after line protocol is in the first line. I wrote a regex below that will give me the group that the word "up" and "vlan20" are located in but is this the best way to achieve this? The regex just seems very long. The will use those values in a conditional statememt.

```
((^Vlan20)(\s\w+)(\s\w+),(\s\w+)(\s\w+)(\s\w+)(\s\w+))
```

Sample text:

```
Vlan20 is up, line protocol is up 
  Hardware is EtherSVI, address is 588d.0939.ffb4 (bia 588d.0939.ffb4)
  Description: MATS Network
  Internet address is 10.88.5.49/28
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit/sec, DLY 100 usec, 
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive not supported 
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:00:04, output never, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 1
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     1992293 packets input, 187299894 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 22809 broadcasts (0 IP multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles 
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     2115535 packets output, 813500880 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 1 interface resets
     89225 unknown protocol drops
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

Comment: Are you trying to do something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/CZ8fbn/1): `^Vlan20.*is\s(\w+)\s*$`?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed That only grabs the "up" value but I need "vlan20" as well.

Comment: If `Vlan20` is a fixed string and always at the beginning, why would you want to "capture" it too? Anyway, you can simply place it in a capturing group as well: `^(Vlan20)......`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I notice when I do ^(Vlan20).*(up) it gives me the results as well. Any drawbacks?

Comment: If you are looking forward vlan20 and up, then I suggest to set your regex as: `^(Vlan20).*(up)`. Use re.search to find the first occurrence (faster).

Comment: @Cheche `^(Vlan20).*(up)` when matched against your input would match all the way up to the `up` in the word `supported` because `.*` being *greedy* does maximal searches. `^(Vlan20).*?(up)` will match only up to ``Vlan20 is up`.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson you're right!..